# Can methods have methods in Python?

Tags: python, object, methods

this may seem a little odd, but it would make for a convenient way for me to finish a bit of code.

Because Python methods are objects themselves, could a method have a method of its own?  That is, if I wanted to do the following (ignoring syntax):

```
def methodCaller(someArgs, methodB):
    # some stuff here . . .
    variableWithAGoodName = methodB()
    jonSkeet = methodB.methodC(variableWithAGoodName)
    return jonSkeet
```

Would it be possible?  My guess is no, but if methods are just objects, shouldn't it be possible somehow?

Thank you so much!

EDIT: I think as has been posted, I am looking for a high-order function.

My question is somewhat academic as I know I could reorganize my code to do this manner of thing totally differently. But, as it is, I am experimenting with Python to learn at least its basics.  I haven't tried this yet, but as I am unfamiliar with Python, it might be possible, just not with this syntax.

Another EDIT: I attempted to be funny with my naming but it made the question unclear.  For that I apologize.  Here is a better example:

```
def MethodA(MethodB):
    # MethodB is passed as a parameter but is also a method.
    # MethodB has a method of its own, somehow, because it is technically still
    # an object.
    MethodB.MethodC() #Let's pretend it returns nothing here.
    # Can this happen?
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. Probably your goal could be achieved by other means, but you have to tell us what it is.

Comment: have you tried that? did it give you any error?

Comment: If `methodB()` were to return objects of different but interface-compatible classes depending on circumstances, your syntax would be fine (with minor modifications). So if B returns a `classD` instance, you end up calling `classD.methodC()` in that case, and `classE.methodC()` if the returned object was a `classE` instance. This is a fundamental concept of object-oriented programming, so I guess you are getting at something else here, but what?

Comment: @F.C. I seem to be able to compile by nesting method definitions.  Do I now have to use special syntax to use it?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: If I recall correctly, nested functions only come into existence when their parent function is called - the nested function's `def` is only run through when the parent function is called. So you can't call them from outside the parent function, **unless** you return the nested function as the `return` value from the parent function. (see: *closures*.) This doesn't really do what you want above, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. Obviously they can have attributes assigned to them which work similarly to methods. Further, functions come with methods already attached- for example, the `__call__` method, which is called with the function.

However, to add a method to an object, what would you typically do? Subclass the object's class, and add the method. However, if you try to subclass function

```
imports types
class F(types.FunctionType):
    pass
```

you'll get this error

```
type 'function' is not an acceptable base type
```

If you want to make a "callable" object, that can have methods and use inheritance, try something like this.

```
class MyCallable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "Look ma, I got called!"

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.print_message()

    def print_message(self):
        print(self.message)


class CallableChild(object):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CallableChild, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print "...as a child, too!"
```

Comment: Interesting; is there then any way to nest "def" declarations that will be visible outside of the encasing method?

Comment: @BlackVegetable not just using 'def' declarations. The funny thing about function attributes is that they aren't accessible from within the function, they can only be set/accessed internally. However, you can definitely pull this off with the callable approach above.

Comment: So you've effectively made an object that masquerades as a function by implementing `__call__()`? (Python's duck typing in action: "it has a `__call__` method, looks like a function to me!)

Comment: @BlackVegetable though your last edit example is possible, you won't be the one writing `MethodC`, it could only be a built-in method of `types.MethodType` or an attribute. Clearly you can emulate this easily, though, with general callables.

Comment: Indeed, the built-in function `callable()` just checks to see whether the object has a `__call__()` method. Note that classes are callable, since you call them to instantiate them! (Their `__call__()` method calls `__new__()` and then `__init__()`.)

Comment: Last comment- technically it is possible to dynamically add methods to any object that will allow you to set other attributes, but it's way dirty and only appropriate for special cases. If you ever need to do that, check out descriptors, the `new` module, and some of @AlexMartelli's weirder Python answers.

Comment: @BlackVegetable For the record, I take my last comment about accessing function attributes from within a function back- it's perfectly possible, but not without the parent function being called. I should've made that clear.

Answer (score 6):

Functions in python are first-class objects with methods and attributes.

```
def foo():
    print("foo")

def bar():
    print("bar")

foo.bar = bar
foo.bar()                  #outputs "bar"

foo.baz = "Hello, world!"
print(foo.baz)             # outputs "Hello, World!"
```

**Edit:**

Because functions are first-class objects, you can also pass them around like any other variable. You can also write "higher-order functions", which are functions of functions (or functions that return functions.)

**Edit 2:**

*[To the tune of 'There ain't no party like an S-Club party!']* There ain't no example like a full-code example!

```
def higher_order_function (input_function):
    input_function.method()

def input_function_1 ():
    print ("exec'ing input_function_1()")

def input_function_1_method ():
    print ("exec'ing input_function_1_method()")

input_function_1.method = input_function_1_method

higher_order_function(input_function_1)
# prints "exec'ing input_function_1_method"
```

Comment: In your example, `bar` isn't really an instance method, it's just a function that also happens to be an attribute of another function object.

Comment: @Wooble: what's the distinction? Educate me. ;)

Comment: A method is a descriptor, for one, while a function is simply an attribute.

Comment: @MattLuongo: Are you saying that a method has access to the function's other methods and attributes (via `self`) while an attribute does not?

Comment: @MattLuongo: In python, there is really not a distinction made between methods, functions, and procedures. The distinction really just arises from how you choose to use them.

Comment: A method has `__get__` and `__set__` methods iteself, and is of type `types.MethodType`.

Comment: Sorry @JoelCornett, that's only half-true. In the sense that you can use them in similar ways, and make them act the same- sure. But they are clearly of different types and works differently, in subtle ways.

Comment: And while you can set attributes on a function, you can't do that on a method, and you can't make a `MethodType` subclass that would take them either.

Comment: @MattLuongo: Ah, yes, I stand corrected. [datamodel](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)